# Applying validation exception when using state_machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, state-machine

I have been unable to find a precise way to accomplish a validation exception on my rails model when using state_machine.

I have as expected a state column in my model and process a validation of emails by passing a user from unverified to verified, simple enough.

My model contains a normal validation of passwords

```
validates :password, length: {minimum: 6}
validates :password_confirmation, presence: true
```

This validation is important, but when passing my user from an unverified to a verified state I run into problems with my model validation as I am only applying an update to a single column, but active record integration with state_machine seems to apply a record update.

The state_machine snippet:

```
state_machine :initial => :unverified do

    event :verify do
      transition :unverified => :verified
    end
```

So the solution would seem to apply an exception to the model validation, I was drawn to :unless as a solution..

I implemented something that I have to say I did not understand fully, which seems to now have the effect of removing any validation on password, obviously making my state_machine process work, but not meeting my objective..

my changes where to add:

```
  validates :password, length: {minimum: 6}, :unless => :proc_no_password_validation
  validates :password_confirmation, presence: true, :unless => :proc_no_password_validation
```

and apply in a private method:

```
def proc_no_password_validation
    Proc.new { |user| user.verify }
  end
```

I have a feeling that directionally I am on the right track, but help to spot my mistake or issue or other solution would be much appreciated.

UPDATE
So I have had some help from Jef on this, but my conclusion was that the model validation method exception route was wrong, I modified my state code as follows:

```
  state_machine :state, :initial => :unverified, :action => :bypass_validation do

    event :verify do
      transition :unverified => :verified
    end

    event :unverify do
      transition :verified => :unverified
    end
  end
```

and then a validation bypass on the state I am interested in ignoring

```
def bypass_validation
    if self.changes['state'][1] == 'verified'
      save!(:validate => false)
    else
      save!(:validate => true)
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:unless` accepts a method name as a symbol or a proc. You gave the name of a method that returns a Proc. As a Proc is not false, your unless condition is met and your validation skipped.

You should use one of :

```
validates :password_confirmation, presence: true, :unless => :proc_no_password_validation
 def proc_no_password_validation
   self.verify
 end

validates :password_confirmation, presence: true, :unless => Proc.new{|user| user.verify}
```

**UPDATE**

state_machine allows you to wrap your validations into states :

```
state :unverified { # or :verified, when should validation apply ?
  validates :password ...
  validates :password_confirmation ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the rapid answer. When I apply the proposed solutions you mention, I unfortunately run into my usual validation issue:Cannot transition state via :verify from :unverified (Reason(s): State cannot transition via "verify", Password is too short (minimum is 6 characters)).. I take it my previous attempt basically just removed validation full stop..

Comment: Jef, the transition happens through a digest code for email validation, which calls the event verify when the digest is validated. Fairly rudimentary to be honest. The challenge here is that I rely on my validation for other changes (update password and expired passwords), so the state_machine only serves to update the status of validation by the end user, I did go down the path of changing tack to use state_machine for all validation, but it seems a lot of extra work, when all I really want to achieve is to update 1 column for 1 user when they have validated their email and track this.

Comment: Sorry we are posting quickly here. I want the password validation to happen for the create and update actions on a user object if you will, so I layer this at the model level for my user object. The email validation is placed in the user model for convenience, but as I am only interested in changing the users validation state for the email, I want for this case to avoid password validation as I am not modifying this value

Comment: Just to check, are you using `user.verify!` ? Second, I can't understand why the validation fails: has the password been set to `nil` between verified and unverified states ? Can you check whether the `proc_no_password_validation` method is called when changing the state ?

Comment: I use user.verify without !. I think the validation fails as the state_machine is attempting to perform an update to column state, but I am guessing applies a row update and not a column update and as the password columns are encrypted the model validation gets confused. So to me there are the two solutions, either skip the validation or find a way to ensure that the update operates on a column only, but I cannot seem to find any hints on this around state_machine. Again thanks for time taken to assist. I see this question in a variety of ways, but no one seems to have the right answer yet..

Comment: I should add here that I use has_secure_password, I do not think this essentially changes anything, but noticed that I had not mentioned it. Which means that there is no 2 records of password to validate, as I am only updating state, which again points to the need to skip this validation step.

Comment: I found a solution, which works, but is not right in my mind. Adding an :if statement to a method,  `validates :password, length: {minimum: 6}, :if => :no_password_validation` and then adopting the exception to only occur if users state is unverified.. `def no_password_validation
    self.state=='unverified'
  end` . Only challenge is that a new user is in this state, so if a user attempts to break the password length rule, they manage to get a record created, but as there is no record the validation does flash an error on password length.. Not elegant, but at least a move forward.

Comment: I think you should try to remove (at least while testing the SM) `has_secure_password`. According to the [API documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/ClassMethods.html), "Validations for presence of password, confirmation of password (using a "password_confirmation" attribute) are automatically added".

Comment: In the end I found another solution, instead of messing with the base validation, I applied an action on the transition in the state_machine, with a callout to a specific method, which in transition from unverified to verified ignores validation (none required)..  `state_machine :state, :initial => :unverified, :action => :bypass_validation do

    event :verify do
      transition :unverified => :verified
    end` and then `def bypass_validation
    if self.changes['state'][1] == 'verified'
      save!(:validate => false)
    else
      save!(:validate => true)
    end
  end`